# Difference between all java life cycles

Tags: java, lifecycle

I am new to java and want to know what are all java life cycles and what is the difference between them. Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of a lifecycle do you mean? Lifecycle of what (a running application, a running component, development history of a project, building with Maven or other tools)?

Comment: I assume, you haven't opened ANY java book yet. I suggest to do so.

Comment: This in not a good question, What lifecycles do you mean?

Comment: for a running application building with maven

Comment: @Reborn Yes I'm new to java

Comment: @CR7 to begin with, maven doesn't deal with 'lifecycles' at all. First open Tutorials Point Java guide, and there is briefly explained anything.

Comment: Thank you @Reborn for your time :) , thank you all guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.0/maven-core/lifecycles.html lists 3 lifecycles:

- default (briefly, this is compile -> test -> package (jar/war/ear/...) -> install -> verify -> deploy)
- clean (just clean)
- site (generates project documentation and reports)

Answer (score 0):

Rather I would suggest you to visit below link to start with :

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/index.htm